# When I hover over 1 button, I want the opacity of a different button to change in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, button, hover

I  want to hover over 1 button, and then the opacity of a different button changes slowly (fades out), using animation in WPF (C#), in the XAML code.

The button I want to change has the x:Name=”HiddenMenu”, however this Style code below is for the button with x:Name=”PlayMenu”, when I hover over the PlayMenu button, I want the opacity of the HiddenMenu button to change. In MainWindow, PlayMenu button references it's style as ('Style="{StaticResource MyMenuButton}"). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyMenuButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="HiddenMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might resolve your issue:

```xml
<Button x:Name="button1">
  <Button.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="button2" Value="0.5"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="button2" Value="0"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

In this example, `button1` is your button and `button2` is the button changing its opacity when button 1 has the mouse over it.
(Here I used setters, but you can perfectly use storyboards here)

Comment: But next time, please read this article before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask